# Google Charts hAxis gridlines dont'work for weekly interval

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization, angular-google-chart

Google charts should draw vertical lines for each data point - it works good for continuous dates like days, months, but when I provide dates with gaps - as sundays only - it stops to draw vertical lines after some count, even if I specify parameter hAxis.gridlines.count:

This is example:
[image]

Note, that major lines for start of month only! This occurs when number of points above ~20. hAxis config:
[image]

Looks like google charts has own logic for some cases or have a bug?

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/niliand/3q79sywk/12/)

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);

function drawBackgroundColor() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

      data.addRows([
        [new Date(2023,04,23), 0],   [new Date(2023,04,30), 10],
        [new Date(2023,05,7), 12], [new Date(2023,05,14), 1],[new Date(2023,05,21), 12], 
        [new Date(2023,05,28), 1], [new Date(2023,06,4), 1], [new Date(2023,06,11), 12],
        [new Date(2023,06,18), 5], [new Date(2023,06,25), 6], [new Date(2023,07,2), 5],
        [new Date(2023,07,9), 5], [new Date(2023,7,16), 3], [new Date(2023,07,23), 15],
      ]);

      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time',
          gridlines: { count: 14 }
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Popularity'
        },
        backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Comment: any chance you could share a working example?

Comment: @WhiteHat Added in the post. (https://jsfiddle.net/niliand/3q79sywk/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found if you go back to [frozen version](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#version-history) 45,
you can get gridlines on each point by using the `ticks` option.

but the chart's sizing appears to work differently with this version.
I needed to add the `chartArea`, `height`, & `width` options to display correctly.

as for the version, I wouldn't recommend using `'current'` anyway,
because a bug in the current version, or a change in how something works might conflict with the chart you built before changes were made.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('45', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'line']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2023, 04, 23), 0],
    [new Date(2023, 04, 30), 10],
    [new Date(2023, 05, 7), 12],
    [new Date(2023, 05, 14), 1],
    [new Date(2023, 05, 21), 12],
    [new Date(2023, 05, 28), 1],
    [new Date(2023, 06, 4), 1],
    [new Date(2023, 06, 11), 12],
    [new Date(2023, 06, 18), 5],
    [new Date(2023, 06, 25), 6],
    [new Date(2023, 07, 2), 5],
    [new Date(2023, 07, 9), 5],
    [new Date(2023, 7, 16), 3],
    [new Date(2023, 07, 23), 15],
  ]);

  var options = {
    backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9',
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 60,
      left: 60,
      height: '100%',
      right: 96,
      top: 16,
      width: '100%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: 'M/d/yy',
      title: 'Time',
      ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0)
    },
    height: '100%',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity'
    },
    width: '100%'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm using angular-google-charts package with some 2021 year version I think, don't think I can manually set version. Looks like this is feature of the later google code.

Comment: Able to use version 45, yes, it works.